# Obtener tabla de valores de distintos parámetros medidos en unas fechas dadas

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla "tomadatos" donde entre otras cosas tengo el campo fecha:

id      |  fecha

1       | 20200301

2       | 20200501

3       | 20200701

Y otra "datos" donde se registra el valor de diferentes parámetros:

parametro |   id_toma  | valor

```
A     |      1     |   33
A     |      2     |   35
A     |      3     |   36
B     |      1     |   10
C     |      1     |   53
C     |      3     |   51
```

Y quiero obtener esta tabla como resultado:

fecha  |  A   |   B    |   C

20200301 |  33  |   10   |  53

20200501 |  35  |  null  |  null

20200701 |  36  |  null  |  51

Cuando para una fecha hay dato de los tres parámetros no tengo problema, pero no logro sacar la tabla completa con los huecos. Está es la consulta que me devuelve los registros de las fechas que tienen valores en los tres parámetros:

```
select tomadatos.fecha as fecha,
A.valor as A,
B.valor as B,
C.valor as C

from tomadatos,
datos as A,
datos as B,
datos as C

where tomadatos.id = A.id_toma and
tomadatos.id = B.id_toma and
tomadatos.id = C.id_toma and
A.parametro='A' and
B.parametro='B' and
C.parametro='C';
```

Comment: ¿ cómo has intentado resolverlo ?

Comment: Esta consulta me devuelve los registros de las fechas que cuentan con los tres parámetros y he intentado meter un full join pero no sé como encajarlo: